# Failed to run shell commands with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

In my terminal if I run: `echo $(pwd)`, I got `/home/abr/workspace`, but when I tried to run this script in python like this:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = ['echo', '$(pwd)']
>>> subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

I get `'\n'`. How to fix this?

Comment: Why would you ever do this instead of using the os package? Seems much easier to use built in functions instead of relying on external calls that are almost definitely os/privilege/system/configuration/terminal dependent. os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir) seems simple enough

Comment: if you hover the mouse over [tag:subprocess] under the question text; you should see the tag's description. Click `info` link under the description. [I've collected questions that are asked again and again there. If you study the questions; you might avoid common issues with using `subprocess` module in the future](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/subprocess/info).

Answer (score 1):

Use `os` package:

```
import os
print os.environ.get('PWD', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cmd = 'echo $(pwd)'
subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

In [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) doc it specified that `cmd` should be a string when `shell=True`.
From the documentation:

> The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use
>   the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is
>   recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

A better way to achieve this is probably to use the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) module from the python standard library, like this:

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
>> "/home/abr/workspace"
```

The [`getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd) function returns a string representing the current working directory.

Comment: This is correct. If you think it adds anything, I'd consider adding that python has built in alternatives which are preferable, or to quote the docs on subprocess: " However, note that Python itself offers implementations of many shell-like features"

Comment: @msn please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html) module:

> If `args` is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string,
>   and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to
>   the shell itself.

You want:

```
subprocess.check_output("echo $(pwd)", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The command `subpreocess.check_output`  will return the output of the command you are calling: 
Example:

```
#echo 2
2
```

from python

```
>>>subprocess.check_output(['echo', '2'], shell=True)
>>>'2\n'
```

the '\n' is included because that is what the command does it prints the output sting and then puts the current on a new line.

now back to your problem; assuming you want the output of 'PWD', first of all you have to get rid of the shell. If you provide the shell argument, the command will be run in a shell environment and you won't see the returned string.

```
subprocess.check_output(['pwd'])
```

Will return the current directory + '\n'

On a personal note, I have a hard time understanding what you are trying to do, but I hope this helps solve it.